# Is it possible to rehearse timing when using LibreOffice Impress the same way PowerPoint does?

Tags: libreoffice-impress

I begin to use LibreOffice. I need to create a presentation file.

So, I use LibreOffice Impress. I usually use reherse timing in Microsoft PowerPoint, because the time is accumulated from the beginning. But, it is different from Impress.

In Impress, the timing is not accumulated from the beginning. So, what do I have to do so the timing in Impress is accumulated from the beginning when rehearse timing?

I use XFCE Manjaro Linux 64-bit

Answer (score -1):

Yes, from the Libre Office documentation, found via a web search: https://help.libreoffice.org/Impress/Rehearse_Timings_of_Slide_Changes

> LibreOffice assists you in defining the right rehearse timings for
> automatic slide changes.
>
> Prepare the slides, start the show using a special icon, tell your
> imaginary audience what you want to tell for the first slide, then
> advance to the next slide and so on. LibreOffice records the display
> time for each slide, so the next time you play the show with automatic
> slide changes, the timing will be as recorded.
>
> **To record a show with rehearse timings**
>
> ```
> 1. Open a presentation, and switch to Slide Sorter View.
> 2. Start the show with the Rehearse Timings icon in the Slide View bar. You see the first slide, and a timer in the bottom corner.
> 3. When it's time to advance to the next slide, click the timer. To keep the default setting for this slide, click the slide, but not the timer. Continue for all slides in your presentation.
> 4. LibreOffice has recorded the display time for each slide. Save your presentation.
> 5. If you want the whole presentation to auto-repeat, open the menu Slide Show - Slide Show Settings. Click Loop and repeat after and OK.
> ```

Comment: Thanks for your response. I mean, how to show accumulated time in slide to slide. Like showing stopwatch. So, I know when I have to stop to talk. In Impress, when I show the next slide, the time show from 0 second. So, I don't know how many minutes I have talked.

Comment: Unless there is a setting to make it behave the way you wish, I'm guessing such a function does not exist. I would expect the official documentation would also inform you if this were an option.